# How can I disable an individual snippet when in shell-script-mode?

Tags: yasnippet

I'm a fairly extensive user of YAsnippet but there is an annoying niggle when I'm working on shell scripts. The default prog-mode snippets includes "fi" which expands to FIXME. This would be fie but it fires every time I close a if<->fi statement in BASH. How can I disable this one snippet when I'm in shell-script-mode?

Answer (score 4):

Add something like this below snippet name:

```
# condition: (not (bound-and-true-p shell-script-mode))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's part of the default snippets bundled with YASnippet. As I find the rest of them useful I'd rather not disable all the bundled snipets (although I have my own directories as well).

Comment: Are those even updated? I've been using a fork of the original snippets for two years now.

Comment: I guess so, on MELPA my current yasnippet dir is yasnippet-20141223.303

Comment: Does it really make sense for someone to update the snippets that **you're** used to? The bunded ones are examples, just fork them and maintain your own.

Comment: Iirc yasnippet looks in the user snippet directory first, so any snippet it finds there would shadow the ones in the bundle.

Comment: The condition didn't work me me. In the end I used "# condition: (not (eq major-mode 'sh-mode))" and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/pull/80)